# What is the purpose for this sample code by using UNION?

Tags: c, unions

There are some example code aboudt design pattern, I have no idea why the first variable "IQRCodeState" has defined in UNION. Can anyone help me explain this specific usage of UNION ?

```
union
{
    IQRCodeState;
    IQRCodeState iqrcodeState;
};
```

more sample codes as follows:

```
typedef struct _IQRCodeState IQRCodeState;

struct _IQRCodeState
{
    void (*getQRCode)(IQRCodeState*);
    void (*scanQRCode)(IQRCodeState*);
    void (*auth)(IQRCodeState*);
    void (*cancel)(IQRCodeState*);
    void (*spend)(IQRCodeState*);
};  

typedef struct _QRCodeStateMachine QRCodeStateMachine;

enum _QRCodeState
{
    NOQRCODE,
    VALID,
    AUTHORIZING,
    AUTHORIZED
};

struct _QRCodeStateMachine
{
    IQRCodeState* currentState;
    IQRCodeState* noQRCodeState;
    IQRCodeState* qrcodeValidState;
    IQRCodeState* qrcodeAuthorizingState;
    IQRCodeState* qrcodeAuthorizedState;
    void (*setState)(QRCodeStateMachine*, enum _QRCodeState);
    union
    {
        IQRCodeState;
        IQRCodeState iqrcodeState;
    };
};

stateMachine->getQRCode(&stateMachine->iqrcodeState);
stateMachine->scanQRCode(&stateMachine->iqrcodeState);
stateMachine->auth(&stateMachine->iqrcodeState);
stateMachine->spend(&stateMachine->iqrcodeState);
```

Comment: That `union` doesn't look valid, I don't think you can have members without names like that. Are you sure this is real code, that compiles?

Comment: @unwind Thanks for helping me. Compiling this program with gcc is ok but it has warning "declaration does not declare anything." Could this definition be right if it is possible for c++ ?